# Getting data from Parse and populating a ListView with it

Tags: android, android-listview, parse-platform, android-adapter

I am getting data from Parse.com and I want to populate it in a ListView dynamicly. Here is my approach:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

ArrayList<Category> categories;

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static CategoryFragment newInstance() {
    CategoryFragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
    return fragment;
}
public CategoryFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ParseQuery<Category> query = new ParseQuery<Category>("Category");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Category>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Category> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if(parseObjects!=null)
                categories = new ArrayList<Category>(parseObjects);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_categories, container, false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    if(categories==null)
        categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    gridView.setAdapter(new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), categories));
    return view;
}
```

The problem is, that the items do not load. I know why, it is because I set the ArrayList to an empty one. I want to know how to do this right. Maybe I should get the data on my adapter?

Comment: check out https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#ui

Comment: How do you add values to categories ?

Comment: @Ricardo manually from parse.com

Comment: In your categories arraylist?

Comment: The ParseQuery runs in the background. It may so happen that the categories list is not even populated before you set the adapter to the gridview. You should use notifyDataSetChanged() method to notify the view to refresh with the new data.